Determining iPad storage capacity without the physical device?
Is there a way to tell how much storage my iPad mini 4 has without looking at the back? I am trying to sell mine but I left it at home. I know the model number (A1538) and ECID but neither of those seem to have any info about the storage of my particular device.

Unfortunately, there is no way to get this info without putting hands-on or having access to the configuration data (from the Apple Store Order Details page).
While your devices are listed under your AppleID (https://appleid.apple.com) and under Devices in Find My (https://icloud.com), there is no notation of the device’s original configuration.
Even with a lookup tool like the one from EveryMac.com, it only gives you generalized specifications not the actual build config. For example, looking up my SN#, it shows storage as 32GB or 128GB.  I just happen to know mine is the 128GB model.
